# Changing Background Color of Modal for angular_components

Tags: angular-dart

How do you customize the background color of the ModalComponent in angular_components for dart?

Question pulled from here: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/187

Answer (score 1):

Changing the dialog colors for modals and other dialogs is as simple as changing the CSS. For example:

CSS:

```
.blue-dialog {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<material-button (trigger)="showBasicDialog = true"
                 [disabled]="showBasicDialog"
                 raised>
  Open Basic Dialog
</material-button>

<modal [visible]="showBasicDialog">
  <material-dialog class="blue-dialog">My Blue Dialog</material-dialog>
</modal>
```